# Best way to get objects from another microservice and mapping that on field

Tags: spring-boot, bigdata

I have 2 applications based on spring-boot framework. I need to map an object by id from another microservice to the field. My pojo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_object")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
public class SampleObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "SAMPLE_FIELD")
    private String sampleField;

    /**
     * ID to get large object from another microservice
     */
    @Column(name = "LARGE_OBJECT_ID")
    private String largeObjectId;

    /**
     * That object i will get from another microservice
     */
    @Transient
    private LargeObject objectFromAnotherService;
}
```

I don't want to get it through the rest requests, because I have around 60.000+ objects, and sending that much requests, I think, is not a good idea. So, my question is: what is the fastest way to get and map an object to my entity? It would've been great if this mapping could occur simultaneously with the process of object creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a **copy of this entity in your database** and take care to maintain it synchronized (if necessary¹) with the another micro service.

So, you need to create a new entity with the same fields, making a relationship with `SampleObject` that makes more sense to the `SampleObject` entity. Like:

```
@ManyToOne
private LargeObject objectFromAnotherService;
```

The `largeObjectId` could be moved to this new entity. So, before create the SampleObject entity, you make a request to the another microservice to get the LargeObject data and create the SampleObject and LargeObject entities.

Another alternative is **map all the fields from LargeObject directly to SampleObject**, without create a exclusive class for that. I don't know the context of your problem, but this approach makes sense in a lot of scenarios.

But **be careful** with this scenario: if these two microservices need so much each other, maybe they need to be together and not separated.

<sup>¹. This is called eventual consistency. As the question not mentioned if is necessary or not, I'm just letting this footnote as reference</sup>

Comment: Why the negative? I can't see much more options when dealing with micro services and having this data dependency from another micro service. The general strategy for theses cases is maintain a copy of the data and working with eventual consistency (if you need to maintain the informations updated).

Comment: I didn't dislike your opinion. I was considering that option (storing information backups in the database). But that information can be edited from another application and that means that I will have to edit it twice. Plus, I will have to do a copy of that information with new values once a month

Comment: I mentioned on the footnote of my answer about eventual consistency. This is the name of the solution for the problem that are you dealing if your concern is synchronize the LargeObject information between two microservices. Maybe your main question is **not how get** the information but **how maintain** them updated.